# Connecting Brother MFC-L2740DW to SMTP via SSL

Tags: email, printer, ssl, smtp

Its very frustrating to see that I bought this MFC-L2740DW just a few weeks ago and its 2014 released printer with AirPrint support. I'm not able to activate a feature called 'scan to email server', the reason I'm not seeing the options to check 'SMTP ssl/tls'. To enable this feature Brother just need to update the firmware or this feature have to be tied with hardware?
some alternative solution suggested for this problem to use stunnel. but I really want to have this feature work as normal. I have another printer MFC9340CDW and it has 'SMTP ssl/tls' option and I am able to 'scan to email server'. so why this feature disabled on MFC-L2740DW ? if so how do I enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

With new firmware update ver 'F' they enabled SSL option for SMTP. Now can scan a doc directly to email without comp.